# How to implement lazy pagination in CouchDB?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I have datatable with many rows, and want to show page numbers + next, previous buttons. Classic Normal pagination. But I only can find docs or information on how to create only Next and Previous buttons functionality, w/o pages. (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/pagination.html)

CouchDB pagination recipe (basic, or altenate methods) has no examples, and no detailed description, on how to implement page numbers. Only information that allows me to implement next, previous buttons.

For good pagination with pages, I need to know:

1. **Total number of objects** (at least)
2. start_key, end_key for every page

How to get this and Is it possible with CouchDB at all?

The only way I see, is to request all the objects from DB and do pagination on frontend.
I guess if you never tried to implement it yourself with CouchDB better not to answer...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Total number of objects (at least)

You must have missed that in all the return examples, the `total_rows` element is still included, so you always have this.

[image]

> 2. start_key, end_key for every page

You're right, if you're using the alternate strategy, as mentioned in [the Jump To Page section](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/pagination.html#jump-to-page) of the docs, you can't implement the page jump mechanism.

Comment: Have you used this approach? On my side it shows totalObjects in DB, not which selected via request params. I was able to create view with reduce: '_count' which only respond with number of all objects selected via request params as single "value" field, which is exactly count we need, but total_rows and offset is not what i need. I thought it will be as well after reading their docs.

Comment: Yes, many times. You're saying that the `total_rows` number is the same when you request your view as when you request `_all_docs`?! If so, then either your view isn't filtering like you expect it to, or there's something very wrong with your CouchDB.